# Update embedded document in mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I have a simple bids model that embeds a supplier:

```
class Bid
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :amount, type: Integer
  embeds_one :supplier
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :supplier
end
```

Many bids have the same supplier. If I was using a scaffolded edit view, how would I update all of the instances of the embedded supplier in bids in the update method?

I have tried, unsuccessfully, something like

```
def update
  @supplier.update(supplier_params)
  #or
  #bids = Bid.where('supplier._id' => @supplier.id)
  #bids.supplier.update_attributes!(supplier_params)
  redirect_to @supplier
end
```

Comment: What do you mean by `How would I update all of the instances of the embedded supplier in bids?` - the question does not make sense since you have an `embeds_one` relationship. Thus updating a bid can never update more than one supplier.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using [nested attributes](https://mongoid.github.io/old/en/mongoid/docs/nested_attributes.html) you should be able to update the nested record by passing `supplier_attributes`.

```
Bid.find(1).update(supplier_attributes: { foo: 'bar' } )
```

To whitelist nested params you use a hash option:

```
params.require(:bid).permit(supplier_attributes: [:foo])
```

To generate the form fields you use `fields_for`:

```
<%= form_for(@bid) do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for(:supplier) do |s| %>
    <%= s.label :foo do %>
      <%= s.text_field :foo %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This is mongoid though, not active record?

Comment: True, wrong docs link but nested attributes in mongoid work almost exactly like in AR. https://mongoid.github.io/old/en/mongoid/docs/nested_attributes.html

Comment: I don't believe there is a big difference in the behaviour of nested  between mongoid 4 and 6 but the v6 docs are really bad. https://docs.mongodb.com/ruby-driver/master/tutorials/6.0.0/mongoid-nested-attributes/

Comment: Yeah, I tried to follow those, but I can't get the format right. What would the actual update line look like in the supplier update method?

Comment: Depends - if the action is something like `PATCH bids/:bid_id/supplier` which is intended to update only the supplier you would just find the bid with the `bid_id` param and update `@bid.supplier` with the params just like any other resource. If what you want is to update the bid and the supplier in the same request you don't really need to anything special besides whitelisting the nested attributes.